# Importing cell function

Tags: vba, excel

I write the code below, I import a column  from a sheet to an other but it just paste me the value. I want that it imports the cell'function too.

```
Sheets("Plan Traitement Risque").Range("B6").Select
lRow = Worksheets("Analyse de risque").Range("B6").End(xlDown).Row
 Worksheets("Analyse de risque").Range("B6:B" & lRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Plan Traitement Risque").Range("B6:B" & lRow)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the 'function' by the end of the range In the code below:

```
Sheets("Plan Traitement Risque").Range("B6").Select
    lRow = Worksheets("Analyse de risque").Range("B6").End(xlDown).Row
     Sheets("Plan Traitement Risque").Range("B6:B" & lRow) = Worksheets("Analyse de risque").Range("B6:B" & lRow).Formula
```

Instead of copying I used '=' because you only paste this once.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: thank you Balinti for your answer, it works. But I still have an other problem in the formula. My formula : "=ConvertCOMPLEXITYToNumber(J6)" use the column J in the first Sheet,but in the second it uses the column K. When I use your syntax, it pastes me the formula applicated on the column J. Do you know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: If it uses other reference in the 2nd sheet, then a simple paste is not what you need. if its only one cell, you can change and correct it with range("X")="Whatever" . In case it not about a single cell, then I will need aditional info in order to help you.